# Error when setting some sheets in code but not with others

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large macro for automating invoices for my company. Sometimes we have proforma invoices that mean we delete two of the three invoices that are manipulated (Client, Owner, and VAT). Therefore I have to check before each code is run whether the sheet exists.

The problem I've run into is that it will give me a *run time error 424* when I set some of the sheets to be checked. In the code below it is the second time that the TVA sheet is checked for where the error occurs (`If TVASheet Is Nothing Then`). Mind you I have almost exactly the same code running above it except it is checking for ClientSheet instead.

```
'If the current payment is the only payment then we add to the TVA invoice 
'that the rest is due
'on the date the balance of rental is due
If (Range("F3") <> "" And Range("G3") = "" And Range("H3") = "") Then

On Error Resume Next
    Set TVASheet = Sheets("TVA Invoice")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If TVASheet Is Nothing Then

    Else

Sheets("TVA Invoice").Select
    If Cells.Find(What:="du paiement sera reçu", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=     _
        xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) Is Nothing Then

    Cells.Find(What:="Select!F3", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Selection.Font.Bold = False
    ActiveCell = _
        "=100 - 100*TEXT(Select!F3,""0%"")&""% du paiement sera reçu le     ""&PROPER(TEXT(Select!C30,""JJ-MMMM-AAAA""))&"""""


    Else
    End If
    End If

Else

On Error Resume Next
    Set TVASheet = Sheets("TVA Invoice")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If TVASheet Is Nothing Then

    Else

Sheets("TVA Invoice").Select
If Cells.Find(What:="du paiement sera reçu", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) Is Nothing Then

    Else

    Cells.Find(What:="du paiement sera reçu", After:=ActiveCell,     LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
        ActiveCell.Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    End If
    End If
    End If


Sheets("Select").Select
```

Comment: The error is probably caused because the variable ```TVASheet``` does not reference object. The ```Is``` operator compares two object references so it is necessary to declare ```TVASheet``` as Worksheet. If you declared it as ```Variant``` and sheet does not exist then the variable is ```Empty``` and the ```Is``` fails with error 424 on the line you specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your `TVASheet` variable at the beginning of your code:

```
Dim TVASheet As Worksheet
```

Obviously the "TVA Invoice" sheet is not found and the `Set` command fails. Because of your `On Error Resume Next` the program continues and the interpreter has no clue what `TVASheet` should be in your `If` clause. You can avoid this by the declaration.

Comment: This may be cus it is the second check. If the first `Set` doesn't fail the second one will never be `nothing` also if it fails later on... it will work if there is a `Set TVASheet = Nothing` in front of the check...

Comment: The first check is in the `if` branch and the second one is in the `else` branch. So just one check will take place while running the function.

Comment: Okay guys, I figured it out. I declared TVASheet in memory on "ThisWorkbook" which updates every time the sheet is changed, so I assumed it would continue to work since I run this program after the worksheet is changed. Especially because it was working before. But when I re-declared it in my macro at the beginning, the problem went away. Thanks @Fratyx